# Can you deep link to an app from a Squarespace hosted website?

Tags: ios, json, mobile, deep-linking, squarespace

I want to implement deep linking in my app. I've read that to implement deep linking you need to put a json file in the root of your website which will then redirect users to the app if they are on a mobile device and the app is installed. I have a Squarespace site, but placing the json file in the root folder of the squarespace files doesn't seem to work. I assume this is because I would need access to squarespaces' own root.

So my question is, can I implement deep linking with a Squarespace site? If so, what have I done wrong? If not, is there an alternative solution, or should I create a new website that I have full access to?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your `apple-app-site-association` file is formatted and named correctly? Have you tried it on a non-Squarespace site?

Comment: I'm pretty confident in the association file, but I don't have a non-Squarespace website to test with.

Comment: I checked with Squarespace support... first rep was decent, but didn't have the depth, so he sent it up the chain. Eventual response: Nope, even in their "developer mode" you cannot get the file in the right place with the right MIME type. Time to look for a different hosting service, or consider **Alex Bauer**'s comment.

Comment: Yeah I also asked their support and had a similar experience. If you make this it's own answer I will mark it, if that doesn't matter to you I'll answer it myself.

Comment: Added an answer, plus a few additional comments on it.

Comment: Thanks again Don.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked with Squarespace support... first rep was decent, but didn't have the depth, so he sent it up the chain.

Eventual response: Nope, even in their "developer mode" you cannot get the file in the right place with the right MIME type.

Time to look for a different hosting service, or consider Alex Bauer's comment.

A couple notes:

- The file *must* be on https:// - plain old http:// won't work.
- The file *cannot* have an extension - so no `.json` on the end.
- The file' MIME-type *must* be set to `application/json`. This *can* be a hassle, as standard web service sets MIME-type by extension.

Otherwise - it's fairly straight-forward :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a soloution.

You can enable a URL Mapping to point on appname://location/xy

This is not a soloution for universal links but you can handle deeplinks in that way.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The requirements around hosting the `apple-app-site-association` file needed by Universal Links are quite strict. I doubt it is possible to satisfy them with the standard Squarespace system, though it *might* be possible via [Developer Mode](https://developers.squarespace.com).

As a workaround, you could add something like the [Branch.io Smart Banner](https://branch.io/smart-app-banner/) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team). This won't make your site URLs active for Universal Links, but it will make it easier for users to transition between your site and the app.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think this is a Squarespace issue as much as a maybe a design issue. If you register the appropriate intents you can make a 1 page to 1 view association in your app. The example below is Android but you can do similar on iOS

Case:

- Web Address: www.abc123.com/news
- App Page: News

Example Intent (Android)

```
<activity
    android:name="com.abc123.android.NewsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_news" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewnews">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http"
             android:host="www.abc123.com"
             android:pathPrefix="/news" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```